# background doesn't stretch

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

I have a jsfiddle included. This is really just fooling around, but i can't get this background to stretch the entire viewport. I think it has to do with the background being 1000px wide stated in the jQuery script, which would make sense. But setting the divs to 100% w/h is not working to stretch that image.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nkgG/)

Just a heads up: there is basically a large gradient i want that is scrolling the page and restarting (the jquery does that) and there is an overlay on top of it that gives it a nice effect.

Div overlay is quite simple:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="overlay" class="png-fix">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot crowd!

Comment: Upload images to some hosting and correct links to images in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [Background images: how to fill whole div if image is small and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779577/background-images-how-to-fill-whole-div-if-image-is-small-and-vice-versa)

There are a lot of ways to do this. I recommend you research before asking a question.

Comment: Embarrassing really lol. So easy i knew the answer, i need sleep. Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

This is also a simple and dynamic solution:

```
background: url(yourimagepath) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```