# Fitting a large background image to fit in a small div

Tags: html, css

So I have an image which is 700px width which is what I'm using as a background image in a div which is 200px width.

I want to keep the image at that size so it can maintain a good resolution for smaller devices.
However the issue I'm having is because the image is larger than the div the image overflows (hidden) but I want the image to resize and fit depending on the size of the div, instead of overflowing.

My div is currently:

```
.featurebox{
background: #F9C112 url(../img/pan1.jpg) no-repeat center top ;
width:200px
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background images: how to fill whole div if image is small and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779577/background-images-how-to-fill-whole-div-if-image-is-small-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define both width and height and then use `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 2):

can you try this?

```
background-size:100%;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

if you use

```
background-size: 100%;
```

the height is set to auto, and can then still overlap.

Comment: I had background-size: cover; . Applied this and it worked for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can set **background-size**:

```css
.featurebox {
background: #F9C112 url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png) no-repeat center top;
background-size: 200px 200px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="featurebox">
</div>
```