# CSS Background Image Too Large

Tags: css, background-image, css-position

I have the following code for a background image on my site.

```
#bg {
height: 200%;
left: -50%;
position: fixed;
top: -50%;
width: 200%;
}

  <div id="bg">
    <img alt="" src="sites/all/themes/marques/images/sponsors.png"  id="bg1">
</div>
```

Link is here:

http://dev-marquesogden.pantheon.io/sponsors

I'm trying to make the image (although very large, to fit within the background.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is not a background image. You are inserting an image into your #bg div. Where are you defining a background image. I dont see it in your code or page source

Comment: Here is the code for the bg img

#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}

Comment: Are you trying to style a background image or a div which contains an image? Becuase your title says background image but your code says its an image inside a div?

Comment: the div should contain the image.but it should work as a background as well. make sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background images: how to fill whole div if image is small and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779577/background-images-how-to-fill-whole-div-if-image-is-small-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work

```
#bg {
    position: fixed;
    /* top: -50%; */
    top: 0;
    /* left: -50%; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(/sites/all/themes/marques/images/sponsors.png);
}
```

and remove `img` from `#bg` element:

```
<div id="bg"></div>
```

By the way this is not good image for this kind of background image purposes (to risky to cut heads).

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

will size the image to fit the viewport width, with the height reacting according aspect ratio. If you'd rather lead with height then it's:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

[more info about background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)