# How do i show the entire image in the container?

Tags: html, css

The image itself is 6024x4024. i can hide the overflow but it seems i cant get it to show the full image in the container. what im seeing is that its zoomed in on the picture.

```css
.section1{
    background-image: url(section1.jpg);
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="section1">

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Change `object-fit` to none. This will not resize the image.
If you want to fill the container (div), then use `fill` in `object-fit`.

Comment: try using background-size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background images: how to fill whole div if image is small and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779577/background-images-how-to-fill-whole-div-if-image-is-small-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. `background-size:contain;`

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <style>
        .section1{
    background-image: url('../Downloads/1.jpg');
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
background-size:contain;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="section1">

        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.section1{
    background-image: url(section1.jpg);
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Change the object-fit to contain it will show entire image.